# AngularJS : How to return a reusable object from a factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

In an AngularJS controller, I have the following defined:

```
app.controller('contentTypeController', ['$scope', '$log', 'abstractDataFactory', 'customFunctions',
    // the abstract data factory accepts controller type parameters for RESTful CRUD

    function ($scope, $log, abstractDataFactory, customFunctions) {

        var dataFactory = new abstractDataFactory("/odata/ContentType");

        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "/odata/ContentType";

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read:

                    function (options) {
                        var odataParams = kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options.data, "read");

                        dataFactory.getList(odataParams)
                            .success(function (result) {
                                options.success(result);
                            })
                            .error (function (error) {
                                console.log("data error");
                            });
                  ...
```

This all works fine.  However, I don't want to have to redefine the `dataSource` in another controller, for this particular data set - ContentType, and would like to abstract it out.

As a result, I created a new `dataSourceFactory`.  I'm not entirely clear on or what the best strategy is for implementing this.

I was thinking that I would like to *new* up the `dataSourceFactory` the same way I did the `abstractDataFactory` from the controller, and those parameters passed on to the `abstractDataFactory` from the `dataSourceFactory`.

After injecting the new `dataSourceFactory` into my controller, it would return various data sources, depending on the method call:

```
var dataSourceFactory = new dataSourceFactory("/odata/ContentType");
var dataSource = dataSourceFactory.contentType();  // .userDetails(), .someOtherData()...
```

From what I understand, Angular factories return functions, so I don't think this is exactly what I'm looking for.

So far, here's my non-working implementation:

Controller:

```
app.controller('contentTypeController', ['$scope', '$log', 'dataSourceFactory', 'customFunctions',

    function ($scope, $log, dataSourceFactory, customFunctions) {

        var dataSourceFactory = new dataSourceFactory("/odata/ContentType");
        var dataSource = dataSourceFactory.contentTypes();  // returns a function, rather than kendo.data.DataSource object
        ...
```

DataSourceFactory:

```
// factory to return datasources
app.factory('dataSourceFactory', function (abstractDataFactory) {

    function dataSourceFactory(odataUrlBase) {
        this.dataFactory = new abstractDataFactory(odataUrlBase);
    }

    dataSourceFactory.prototype = {
        contentTypes: function () {
            new kendo.data.DataSource({
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read:

                        function (options) {
                            var odataParams = kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options.data, "read");

                            this.dataFactory.getList(odataParams)
                                .success(function (result) {
                                    options.success(result);
                                })
                                .error(function (error) {
                                    console.log("data error");
                                });

                        }
               },
                batch: false,
                pageSize: 10,
                serverPaging: true,
                change: function (e) {
                    console.log("change: " + e.action);
                    // do something with e
                },
                schema: {
                    data: function (data) {
                        //console.log(data)
                        return data.value;
                    },
                    total: function (data) {
                        console.log("count: " + data["odata.count"]);
                        return data["odata.count"];
                    },
                    model: {
                        id: "ContentTypeId",
                        fields: {
                            ContentTypeId: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            //UserId: {editable: false, nullable: false },
                            Description: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                            //msrepl_tran_version: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } }
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    //var response = JSON.parse(e.responseText);
                    var response = e.status;
                    console.log(response);
                }
            })  // dataSource
        }  // contentTypes
    };

    return dataSourceFactory;

});
```

In summary,

```
var dataSource = dataSourceFactory.contentTypes();  // returns a function, rather than kendo.data.DataSource object
```

**1)** Data source has to be the value of the new `kendo.data.DataSource` object, rather than a function.  Since the factory returns the function, how can I make use of it in my controller, and is this the right way of going about this, and if not suggestions?

**2)** I will have various data sources defined in the `dataSourceFactory` and used as mentioned above.  Is this recommended (I'm going for code reuse, and not a bunch of separate factories for each data source), and if not, suggestions?

Comment: Typically services are singletons and factories create instances on demand.

Comment: So my initial setup, I believe is correct - I'm creating a new on-demand instance of the `dataSourceFactory` with a specific `oDataUrl` value.

Comment: factories doesn't have to return functions, they can return whatever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the subtle nudge from the comments, I was able to figure this out.

The first issue was that I wasn't actually returning anything from the function call (missing the `return` statement from `contentTypes:`).

Secondly, I had to define a `dataFactory` inside the `dataSourceFactory` that represented the `abstractDataFactory`:

```
app.factory('dataSourceFactory', function (abstractDataFactory) {
    var dataFactory;

    function dataSourceFactory(odataUrlBase) {
        dataFactory = new abstractDataFactory(odataUrlBase);
    }

    dataSourceFactory.prototype = {
        contentTypes: function () {
            return new kendo.data.DataSource({ ... }...
```

What I'm still not clear on, is if this is a good way to go - having all my data source objects returned by one factory.